# mod_rewrite - absolute path of a folder

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite, right now and i'm using this

```
RewriteRule ^.+(css/.+)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.+(js/.+)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.+(img/.+)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.+(fonts/.+)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.+(swf/.+)$ $1 [L]
```

Now i just write css/cssfile.css and js img and stuff and it works (even if i dont think this is the right way)

But anyways, i have a folder named functions with some PHP file, and i tried to make the same with that that i maked with this.. But that didnt go to great, the reason i want this is i want to make one file with includes, so i avoid, making several rows of code unnecessarily.

Does anyone knows what im talking about and maybe have a clue what i should do?

I'm sorry for bad explination (new to mod_rewrite) and i tried to search with out any good response..

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "that didn't go too great"? What was the code you tried, and what happened? I'm also not clear what you're trying to do, as PHP's `include` statement has absolutely nothing to do with `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: On another note, are these rules just so that you can include CSS files etc in HTML with `href="css/cssfile.css"` but still fetch them from the root directory? If so, why not just use `href="/css/cssfile.css"` instead? Doing it this way will be really bad for browser caching, for instance, as the same CSS file will appear at different URLs as you click around the site.

Comment: With this code i only have to write css/file and now i want that for the functions map as well, right now i have this code in my PHP doc: `../../../functions/connect_db.php` i really want it to work like this: `functions/connect_db.php`

Comment: It seems you want to autoload your classes in functions. For this maybe you would like to use php autoload http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

With autoload you have not to include your clases. You define an autoload function responsible to look up your included classes wherever you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `include` statement does not resolve a URL or ask Apache for any information, so `mod_rewrite` will not affect its behaviour in any way.

What you are looking for is a way to define the location of your files relative to the "document root" (the directory that maps to `example.com/`) rather than relative to the current file.

For this you can use the PHP variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, e.g.

```
 include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/functions/connect_db.php';
```

It might also be an idea to move the function definitions one directory *above* the document root, so that they can't ever be loaded as URLs in their own right. The function [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname) gives the "parent" directory of a particular path, so you might instead use:

```
 include dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/functions/connect_db.php';
```